# MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.Tool not analyzing .cs files

Tags: c#, sonarqube, teamcity, code-metrics

I am trying to use Sonarqube for code analysis with team city integrated using cake build.

For some reason Sonarqube does not analyze .cs files.(currently analyzes js/css/xml)

Is it a problem with the agent being used for the build?
Some settings to be done in Sonarqube/Teamcity?

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the project happen to contain cshtml files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Roslyn compiler on build agents needed to be updated as Sonar required newer versions.